# How to get rotational invariance for non-Euclidean metrics?

Tags: geometry, metric-spaces

For the Euclidean distance metric you have invariant length under common rotation.

Is this something special to the Euclidean metric or can you define a new special rotation to make something like the Manhattan distance metric also have rotational invariance under the new special type of rotation?

Comment: Common rotations and the Euclidean metric behave like they are made for one another. So neither is really special on their own (except for, you know, how well they apply to the actual real world), but they go together nicely. Each metric has its own set of isometries, and I believe that Manhattan distance doesn't really have that many rotation-like transformations.

Comment: Manhattan distance does have invariance under what might be seen as $90^\circ$ rotations and combinations of these

Comment: Does Manhattan metric have any continuous invariants?

Comment: The only isometries of the 1-norm and the $\infty$-norm are reflections in the axes and the group generated from them (including rotations by $90^\circ$).

Comment: So is the 2-norm the only one with a continuous isometry - something like rotational invariance?